# How can we add file in project directory using javascript onclick?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

How can we possibly add a file in our project directory using the javascript onclick is it possible? Need your help guys. I have done many research about this and nothing helped. If possible I dont want to add enctype multipart/form-data in my form because it wont allow me to store my data to mysql.

```
<form class="add-music-form" action="/save" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="song-feaured-image">
            <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="featured_img"  onchange="loadFile(event)" required>
            <img id="output" class="image-preview" width="130" src="/img/rock-on.jpg" />
            <label for="file" class="attach_file" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" id="title" name="title" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Band name" id="band_name" name="band_name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="custom-file">
        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" name="audio" required>
        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Select audio file</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
        <a onclick="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
    </div>
</form>

<script>
function submit() {
    let upload_img = document.getElementById("output");
    //--------------???----------------//
}
</script>
```

> app.js

```
app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
    let sql = "INSERT INTO `music`(`featured_img`, `title`, `band_name`, `audio`) VALUES ('" + req.body.featured_img + "', '"+req.body.title+"', '"+req.body.band_name+"', '"+req.body.audio+"')";
    let query = connection.query(sql, (err, results) => {
        if(err) throw err;
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by project directory?

Comment: yah the image i input will store in my project folder /uploads

Comment: You need a server to accept, store, and return a link to the client.

Comment: I have mysql server I want to store only the filename and the file will store on project folder

Comment: @AdamAzad Hi I uploaded new question in relation to this topic here please need your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231481/mysql-store-undefined-string-in-nodejs-multipart-form-data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note: I had trouble getting this working with EJS)

/client/index.html

```
<form class="add-music-form" action="/save" method="POST">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="song-featured-image">
            <input style="display: none;" type="file" accept="image/*" id="file" name="featured_img" required>
            <img id="output" class="image-preview" width="130" src="/img/rock-on.jpg" />
            <label for="file" class="attach_file" style="cursor: pointer">
            <i class="material-icons">attach_file</i></label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-3">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <a onclick="cancel()" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</a>
        </div>
</form>
```

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
var app = express();

app.use(fileUpload());
app.use(express.static('client'));

app.listen(80, function () {
    console.log("Server loaded.");
});

app.post('/save', (req, res) => {
    let fileName = req.files.featured_img.name;
    let data = req.files.featured_img.data;
    console.log(fileName);
    console.log(data);
    // Do SQL
});
```

Comment: No enctype="multipart/form-data" dont allow me to send my data to mysql that is why i want to know if it is possible for javascript to store my file.

Comment: mysql is the database. You haven't mentioned what your server platform is, e.g. node.js, php, etc.

Comment: Hi I uploaded new question in relation to this topic here please need your help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231481/mysql-store-undefined-string-in-nodejs-multipart-form-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63231481/mysql-store-undefined-string-in-nodejs-multipart-form-data

I have new question maybe i can mark yours as answered too